# require(...) is not a function - importing Sequelize model

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I've created a Sequelize model in TypeScript that I'm exporting using `export default ...`:

```
import { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

interface UserAttributes {
  id: number,
  name: string,
}

export default (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
  class User extends Model<UserAttributes>
    implements UserAttributes {
    declare id: number;

    declare name: string;
  }

  User.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

and then I dynamically import all models created in a specified folder inside `index.ts`:

```
fs.readdirSync(PATH_TO_MODELS)
  .forEach((file) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line import/no-dynamic-require, global-require
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, PATH_TO_MODELS, file))(sequelize, DataTypes);
    // some processing on said model...
  });
```

However, when running this file, I receive the error `TypeError: require(...) is not a function`. I'd prefer to keep the model as a default export - how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use import method of sequelize.

Working example with sequelize version < 6:

```
Fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(
    (file) =>
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js',
  )
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(Path.join(__dirname, file))
   
  })
```

Comment: Looks like the `import()` method has been deprecated: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/12175

Comment: Which node and sequelize version you are using?

Comment: sequelize v6.3.5, node v14.17.6

Comment: If you are using sequelize version >= 6.0 then below link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556633/sequelize-6-import-models-from-file